# Is there a way to compile with a generic type?

Tags: swift, generics

This is something that has vexed a number of developers including myself. Let say we have a protocol that defines a subscript which we apply to a simple class.

```swift
protocol Cache {
   subscript<Value>(_: String) -> Value? { get set }
}

class InMemoryCache: Cache {
    private var cache: [String: Any] = [:]
    subscript<Value>(key: String) -> Value? {
        get { 
            cache[key] as? Value 
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue {
                cache[key] = value
            } else {
                cache.remove(key)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This works fine as long as we know the types:

```swift
cache["abc"] = 5
let x: Int? = cache["abc"]
```

but the developers want to do this:

```swift
cache["abc"] = nil
```

Which won't compile because the compiler cannot determine the `Value` generic type. This works however

```swift
cache["abc"] = nil as String?
```

I've tried a number of things but they all have drawbacks. Things like adding a second subscript with the `Any` type. Nothing seems to work well even though it would seem like a simple problem.

Has anyone found a solution that handles `cache["abc"] = nil`?

Comment: I don’t think you can do this and to be honest the use case is a bit strange, with a cache that holds `Any` you must always know the type of the value you are reading.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson setting a value to `nil` is the canonical way of removing an item from the container (e.g. a `Dictionary`). The use case is therefore fairly common. The problem here is the ambiguity: The cache can contain optional types. So are we trying to delete the element or store `Optional<Something>.none`? We can't tell, and neither can the compiler.

Comment: It's opinion based: may be somebody like `cache["abc"] = nil as String?`, may be somebody have added `cache.remove("abc")`

Comment: @Cy-4AH it's not opinion based. The question is explicitly "how can I make `cache["abc"] = nil` compile. And there is an answer that fulfils the requirement.

Comment: @JeremyP When I wrote that the use case was strange I referred to the usage of `Any` as the value type for a cache and it had nothing to do with wanting to remove a value by setting it to nil. Not sure how that was misunderstood but now you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing your protocol requirements somewhat.

Have the protocol require a subscript that does *not* use generics, and returns an `Any?`.

```swift
protocol Cache {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? { get set }
}
```

This subscript will let you do the following:

```swift
cache["abc"] = 5
cache["abc"] = nil
let value = cache["abc"] // value is an `Any?`
```

but it will *not* let you do this:

```swift
let number: Int? = cache["abc"] // error
```

So, let's fix that by adding another subscript to `Cache`. This subscript is equivalent to your original subscript requirement, except it doesn't need a setter and will call the other subscript (the one required by the protocol):

```swift
extension Cache {
    subscript<Value>(key: String) -> Value? {
        self[key] as? Value
    }
}
```

(If you're worried that this subscript calls itself, don't be. `self[key]` here actually calls the other subscript, not this one. You can confirm this in Xcode by command-clicking on the `[` or the `]` in `self[key]` to jump to the definition of the other subscript.)

Then, implement the required subscript in your class:

```swift
class InMemoryCache: Cache {
    private var cache: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        get { cache[key] }
        set { cache[key] = newValue }
    }
}
```

This will allow all of the following to compile:

```swift
let cache = InMemoryCache()
cache["abc"] = 5
let x: Int? = cache["abc"]
cache["abc"] = nil
```

Comment: Yers this is pretty much where I arrived after posting the SOF question. Why is it that posting a question is the one thing I need to do to work out a solution? :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to have your desire output.

Because this is a dictionary so you get assign `nil` directly in your `InMemoryCache`

```swift
class InMemoryCache: Cache {
    private var cache: [String: Any] = [:]
    subscript<Value>(key: String) -> Value? {
        get {
            cache[key] as? Value
        }
        set {
            if let value = newValue {
                cache[key] = value
            } else {
                cache[key] = nil // make nil directly here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In here because of `Value` is a generic type. So you can not assign `nil` directly. It must have a specific type.

Instead you can do like this

```swift
let nilValue : Int? = nil // any type nil you want
cache["abc"] = nilValue
```

or directly cast it to nil of any tupe before assign to dictionary

```swift
cache["abc"] = (nil as String?)
```

It will refresh anything value is store in the key.

Example

```swift
// value
let nilValue : Int? = nil
var number : Int? = nil
var string : String? = nil

cache["abc"] = 5
number = cache["abc"] // Optional.some(5)

cache["abc"] = "abc"
number = cache["abc"] // nil
string = cache["abc"] // Optional.some("abc")

cache["abc"] = nilValue 
number = cache["abc"] // nil
string = cache["abc"] // nil
```

Comment: Actually that's not solving the problem. The problem was to see if I could find a way to set `nil` without having to cast it.

Comment: Dear @drekka, because ``Value`` here must know type in my knowledge. So I think you can not directly set ``nil`` like you want. But you can set nil at any type, it will automatically delete the store value at that key in dict. No need to be at right type

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are having a hard time with this is because

```
cache["abc"] = nil
```

cannot be compiled. There is not enough information to infer the generic type of the subscript - or of the optional value. The compiler sees something like

```
cache<?>["abc"] = Optional<?>.none
```

How is it supposed to figure out what to put in place of the question marks?

There's another ambiguity. Your cache can contain any type, even `Optional`. When you are assigning `nil` to the subscript, how does anybody know if you want to remove the element or store an instance of `Optional<Something>.none` at the subscript?

When I find myself fighting the language in this way, I usually try to take a step back and ask if I am perhaps doing something fundamentally bad. I think, in this case, the answer is yes. You are trying to pretend something is more strictly typed than it really is.

I think your getter/setter should explicitly take a value that is of type `Any`. It works better and it has the advantage that it explicitly documents for the user that a `Cache` conforming type can store anything in it.

For this reason, I would say TylerP's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73944407/169346) is the best. However, I would not create a subscript in the extension, I would define a function

```
extension Cache
{
    func value<Value>(at key: String) -> Value?
    {
        self[key] as? Value
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that the compiler can get confused when you have multiple subscripts with similar signatures. With the extension above, I can conform `Dictionary<String, Any>` to the protocol and not need a new class.

```
extension Dictionary: Cache where Key == String, Value == Any {}

var dict: [String : Any] = [:]

dict["abc"] = 5
let y: Int? = dict.value(at: "abc")
dict["abc"] = nil
```

Obviously, the above won't be useful to you if you need reference semantics for your cache.

Answer (score 0):

TylerP's solution was pretty much bang on the money. For completeness though, here's what the code now looks like:

```swift
protocol Cache {

   /// Handles when we need a value of a specific type.
   subscript<Value>(_: String) -> Value? { get }

   /// Handles getting and setting any value. 
   /// The getter is rarely used because the generic getter above 
   /// is used. Setting a value compiles because we don't care what 
   /// type is it. Setting a `nil` also compiles for the same reason. 
   subscript(_: String) -> Any? { get set }
}

class InMemoryCache: Cache {

    private var cache: [String: Any] = [:]

    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        get { cache[key] }
        set {
            if let value = newValue {
                cache[key] = value
            } else {
                remove(key)
            }
        }
    }

    subscript<Value>(key: String) -> Value? {
            cache[key] as? Value 
    }
}
```